# How do you "speak" a function name to another programmer in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

In c#, if I wanted to tell another programmer to look at a specific function such as `Person.GetAge()` I would "speak" that function something like...

"Look at Person dot GetAge"

In objective-c this function is `[Person getAge]` (there is no "dot"). How do people "speak" this to other developers?

Comment: You shouldn't be naming your methods `-getAnything` (just `-anything` is correct), so you should just say "Person age" for the `-[Person age]` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally just read it like it's written, with a short pause between the class and method name.  For methods like `animationDidStop:finished:context:` I don't even bother with the colons.

Answer (score 0):

I say it the same as I do in any other language... "person's get age".  There is no need for the "dot" as it is simply used to denote what class the member belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the naming conventions, the selector is supposed to read much like a sentence.
(getAge is a nono)

-[Person age] would just be "Person age"
-[UIView animationDidStop:@"anim" finished:YES context:NULL] would be "UIView animation did stop, anim, finished, yes, context, NULL"

You'll also see some with withContext and things like that, to make them even more sentence like.